# Web site not pulling data properly from SQL after server transfer

Tags: sql, iis-7, web, windows-server-2008, nopcommerce

We have a website we would like to transfer to our Server 2008, IIS7 site which uses [NOPCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com). We imported the database, set up the web.config and the database connects. The issue, it seems, is that it's not pulling the data.

For example: The registration page should be like:

```
First Name  
Last Name  
Gender  
Birth Date
```

Instead its like

```
account.firstname  
account.lastname  
account.gender  
account.dob
```

We ensured the site has proper access to the DB and it does connect(it yields an error page if it doesn't)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was related to mounting the database. It seems the primary keys were set to the lowest available value instead of the proper one,